# ERROR: While executing gem ... (ArgumentError) ... is not an octal string

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently using this code:

https://github.com/fulldecent/html-proofer-mailto_awesome/commit/5fb5ab3e8e5e7cf90c0e666e91dbcc030d035244

and attempting to push a gem to the world with:

```
gem push html-proofer-mailto_awesome.gemspec
```

but it produces the error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
>       "equire '" is not an octal string

---

I have tried many things, including adding blank new lines at the top of the file. It seems that adding one character, any character, offsets the error string by one byte.

In other words, the 100th byte (±) of this file is an error regardless of the contents of the file at that location.

---

I, just, the, please help.

Comment: Sometimes computers behave so strangely, that it is best to post on SO, step away from the keyboard and do about 50 push ups.

Comment: Have you tried `gem build html-proofer-mailto_awesome.gemspec` and then `gem push html-proofer-mailto_awesome.gemspec-1.0.0.gem`?

Comment: What version of rubygems-update are you using? Does updating it resolve the issue?

Comment: Thank you, build and push worked. Wow, that could be documented better.

Answer (score 1):

Answer within question's comments: building the gem with

```
gem build html-proofer-mailto_awesome.gemspec
```

makes it possible to successfully push it with

```
gem push html-proofer-mailto_awesome.gemspec-1.0.0.gem
```

Thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5399937/tom).